# Ubuntu 14.04(32-bit) : Is it necessary to reinstall ubuntu after adding more RAM?

Tags: 14.04, ram

I have 2 GB RAM , I want to add 2 GB of more RAM. Will it be necessary to reinstall ubuntu 14.04 after adding more RAM? I do not want to reinstall as well as I need ubuntu to fully use the newly added RAM.

Comment: No. Any new memory should be detected and used. A 64-bit SO is recommended for +2GB.

Comment: yes i know but currently i need more RAM without loosing any data on 32-bit ubuntu.

Comment: You don't need to reinstall but you system also may not use all the new RAM. If it's 64-bit hardware then a backup and a fresh install of 64-bit is preferable.

Comment: >>but you system also may not use all the new RAM.
this is the thing which i want to know, Thanks! I would definitely install 64-bit ubuntu now.

Comment: You may also need to adjust your swap partition. How much swap do you have now? Type `free -h` in terminal to find out.

Comment: i have 2 GB swap

Comment: Start new comments with `@heynnema` or I won't see them. With 4G RAM, I'd recommend a 4-8G swap.

Comment: I have followed your instructions and it is working fine even today after 7 months. Thanks!

Comment: Great news! Thanks for the update. Let me put that into an answer and maybe you can accept it, ok? Give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: Accepted your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments...

The user wants to upgrade from 2G RAM to 4G RAM, and asks if anything else is required. They're running 32-bit 14.04. If they add more than 4G total RAM, they will have to install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu. We discussed it, and decided that the user would increase their swap partition (or swapfile) from 2G to 4-8G.

Update #1:

Everything is running fine now.